# wp8 Lock screen content

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, lockscreen

How can I set multi-line text in the top part of the lock screen. I know it can be achieved by setting **LockScreen_Notification_TextField** in the bottom below the clock, but it allows just 3 lines. My text is much bigger and want to be displayed above the clock. 
For example look at this app: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/the-quote/1db336cc-88c9-403d-a0a8-261e5eeb90f6

Is it necessary to edit the image every time the lock screen is changed or it gets the content from live tile?

Please provide me some steps or tutorial to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, this text is rendered on `LockScreen` image. This is not system text displayed in the top

Comment: do you have any working example or something similar how to achieve this ?